# How to get sum of largest numbers in each individual row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How would I go about getting sum of largest numbers in each individual row in Google Sheets?  For example, let's say we have three rows (1, 2, 3) with two columns each (A, B).  This formula would take the larger number in row 1 from A1 and B1, the larger number in row 2 from A2 and B2, and take the larger number in row 3 from A3 and B3, and sum those numbers up.

Answer (score 6):

```
=SUM(MAX(A1,B1)+MAX(A2,B2)+MAX(A3,B3))
```

This works only for 3 rows.

A general solution would be following,

In a new column (say C) put this formula

```
=MAX(A1,B1)
```

Then apply this formula on some other cell.

```
=SUM(C:C)
```